# Possible to change the preview screen size?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

i have my gutenberg custom block previewing ok but i was wondering if there was a way to override the size of the 'hover preview window' as currently it's displaying the mobile styles for the block and not the desktop styles.

please see image for reference.

[image]

I ideally would like the preview image to be landscape rather than portrait, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a CSS Classname.

In the Gutenberg [repo](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/inserter/style.scss) you can see that the element gets its with from a internal variable.

Specifically `$block-inserter-width: 350px;` on line 2 in [Style.css](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/inserter/style.scss#L2)

You'll want to overwrite [`.block-editor-inserter__main-area`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/df8e78359d08e7a4527591163d1d180e0dd9e122/packages/block-editor/src/components/inserter/style.scss#L81) and
[.block-editor-inserter__quick-inserter](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/df8e78359d08e7a4527591163d1d180e0dd9e122/packages/block-editor/src/components/inserter/style.scss#L281).